# Django upload file?

Tags: django

### How can I upload a file using Django?

I have followed [these instructions to upload files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/)

Here, I am not getting any error, but when I submit my form, the other 
details in the form got saved into db. But my uploaded file is not saved anywhere.

### /models.py/

```
class resmodel(models.Model):
   resume_header = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   upload_resume = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
```

### /forms.py/

```
class resmodelForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = resmodel
```

### /views.py/

```
def resview(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = resmodelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        a = resmodel(resume_header=resume_header, upload_resume = request.FILES['upload_resume'])
        a.save()
        return render_to_response('/profile/save/success/')
else:
    form = resmodelForm()
    return render_to_response('resume.html', {'form': form})
return render_to_response('resume.html')
```

### /resume.html/

```
<form action="." method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
<table border="0" align="center" cellsapcing="1" cellspadding="1">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><h3> Personal Information</h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Resume Header<sub>(250 words max)</sub></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="resume_header"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Upload Resume<sub>(.doc/.docx, rtf, pdf, txt)</sub></td>
    <td><input type="file" name="upload_resume" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="reset" value="RESET">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

### /urls.py/

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', (r'^profile/$', resview),)
```

### /settings.py/ In settings my media path and url is..

```
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/var/www/uploadresume/resume/media/'
```

**This is my code.
Fix my mistakes if there?**

Comment: maybe you should post the codes that you have created than you give a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to used `form.save()` than manually save it

```
def resview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = resmodelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render_to_response('/profile/save/success/')
    else:
        form = resmodelForm()
    return render_to_response('resume.html')
```

you forgot to put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>`

```
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    ..........
</form>
```

Comment: Hey its worked, great, thanks a lot. Can u give me some tricks to upload files without using forms.py

Comment: it's possible, but how about your other fields?

Comment: other fields in the sense?

Comment: I mean other field, the `resume_header`. Never mind, I will help you just create another question for that.

Comment: yes the resume_header and the filename got saved into db. my file was saved into media/documents folder. And i saw ur blog, Its good and great.

Comment: Could u tell me how to upload the file without using forms.py in the above example

Comment: OK I will just post it in my blog. I will create it later and I will give you a link

Comment: http://catherinetenajeros.blogspot.com/2013/04/upload-image-using-modelform-and-manual.html